# Is there any way to add "view count","like count","comment count" columns for each page inside a Site Pages library of a Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm getting site pages properties from ajax call but properties do not include read count, Like count and comment count. But i can get the properties like description , title. I want to create a column which displays the like ,comment, view  count of each pages. Is there any way to that?